# Android: Displaying Images From SDcard

Tags: android

I have an app on the market that displays all photos from the user's SDcard in a gallery. Initially I had out of memory issues, but alleviated those by increasing the inSampleSize in the BitmapFactory options. However, I still have intermittent reports of images not displaying, in some cases none at all. There seems to be a larger proportion of Droid Eris users having problems. Here is the method that loads all photos and the accompanying ImageAdapter:

```
    private void loadAllPhotos() {
    setContentView(R.layout.add_pictures);      
    String[] projection = {MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails._ID};
    cursor = managedQuery( MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
            projection, 
            null,       
            null,
            MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.IMAGE_ID);
    column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails._ID);
    int size = cursor.getCount();
    if (size == 0) {
        Toast.makeText(thisContext, "Can't find pics on SDcard.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    g = (Gallery) findViewById(R.id.gallery);
    g.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));  
}
```

The ImageAdapter:

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    int mGalleryItemBackground;
    public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
        TypedArray a = obtainStyledAttributes(R.styleable.Gallery1);
        mGalleryItemBackground = a.getResourceId(R.styleable.Gallery1_android_galleryItemBackground, 0);
        a.recycle();
    }
    public int getCount() {
     int cursorCount = mCursor.getCount();
      return cursorCount;
    }
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
      ImageView i = new ImageView(mContext);
      System.gc();
      if (convertView == null) {                                        
         try {
             String [] proj={MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
             mCursor = managedQuery( MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,proj, null, null, null); 
             column_index = mCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
             mCursor.moveToPosition(position);
             filename = mCursor.getString(column_index);
             if (filename.endsWith(".jpg") || filename.endsWith(".png")) {
                 BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                 options.inSampleSize = 15;
                 Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filename, options);
                 i.setImageBitmap(bm);
                 i.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
                 i.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(150, 150));
                 i.setBackgroundResource(mGalleryItemBackground); 
                 System.gc();
             }
         } catch (Exception e) { 
         } 
      }
           return i;
    } 
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have not done so already, integrate Flurry or DroidDrop or something to collect exceptions, as they may shed some light on your problem.

Also:

1. Please recycle your `Views`! You are creating a new `ImageView` on every `getView()` call, which is not helping your GC situation.
2. You are calling the same `managedQuery()` on every `getView()` call, which is horrible. Do that once, please.
3. You seem to be accessing `mCursor` in `getCount()` before it is initialized in `getView()`.
4. `column_index` should always be `0` in the way you are calling `managedQuery()`, so you should not need to use `getColumnIndexOrThrow()`. Even if you want to use that, only do that once, when you make your single `managedQuery()` call.

Whether any of that will clear up your Droid Eris problems, though, I cannot say.

Comment: Thanks very much for the feedback. I already use custom error reporting that allows users to email me the stack trace when an exception occurs.

I'll make the changes you suggest and see how things go.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the code above, it works well only if you have just .png and .jpg on the SD. Otherwise it can get some strange path out of the mCursor and in that case will show nothing.