# coverflow for camera pictures in android

Tags: android

Can anybody help me in implementing cover flow for my camera pictures? I am taking pictures in my app using the default camera and storing pics in a separate folder in the sd card. I want to apply coverflow to those pics. I checked many available resources, but found only how I can apply coverflow to the pics in the drawable folder. Any Help is deeply appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [quite lenghty tutorial](http://www.inter-fuser.com/2010/02/android-coverflow-widget-v2.html) on how to do this

Comment: Hey I have seen this , but this is also focused on how to use cover flow for images in the drawable folder. I want to show my camera pics with this animation of cover flow

Comment: You have to [make your own ImageAdapter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2388606/android-displaying-images-from-sdcard) that sifts through the Media directory

Comment: Still I didn't get any solution on how to get it.